# VBA Print as PDF

Tags: vba

How do I save as PDF an Excel Print File automatically without Asking for Filename or showing the adobe reader.

This is for automated email with attachments.

I dont need Excel Necessarily as I will use Outlook VBA to retrieve records then align it, excel, crystal rep, save it as PDF and attach.

Comment: I'm sorry i'm not native in english, i didn't understand clearly. Do you need to save your excel file as pdf?

Comment: not really. I just want to print something and save it as PDF. For example I use HTML, I generate a code with properalignment everything then print them as PDF. A Client of mine want it as PDF and not as HTML or Excel.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your document looks like so it might not quiet cut it but you can save every worksheet of your document as pdf file like this:

```
Sub Mac()
Dim wsh As Worksheet, vWshs, vWshName

vWshs = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")
With ActiveWorkbook
    For Each vWshName In vWshs
        .Worksheets(vWshName).ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
            "C:\Tmp\" & vWshName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
    Next vWshName
End With
End Sub
```